# Accepting array style urlencoded parameters with ring

Tags: php, clojure, ring

I'm replacing an old PHP API with one implemented in Clojure.  The API has an endpoint that accepts array style parameters, for example:

```
http://localhost/create?person[name]=John&person[gender]=m
```

PHP would yield this:

```
array(
    "person" => array(
        "name" => "John",
        "gender" => "m"
    )
)
```

We're currently using Ring's [wrap-params](http://clojuredocs.org/ring/ring.middleware.params/wrap-params) to process the parameters.  If you look at the [source](https://github.com/mmcgrana/ring/blob/master/ring-core/src/ring/util/codec.clj#L100) for ring's input decoding, you'll see that ring takes a simple view of decoding the input parameters - just split it on the `&` and `=`.  It therefore yields the following:

```
{"person[name]" "John"
 "person[gender]" "m"}
```

To be explicit, in Clojure, I'd want the following parameters:

```
{"person" {"name" "John"
           "gender" "m"}}
```

How can I set up my ring app to properly accept the array style parameters supported by PHP?  Is there any third party middleware I can use?

Comment: [`ring.middleware.nested-params`](http://ring-clojure.github.io/ring/ring.middleware.nested-params.html#var-nested-params-request) seems to be the solution. Working on implementing it properly at the moment, documentation is a bit sparse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to support these nested parameter arrays, that functionality is provided in the [`ring.middleware.nested-params`](https://github.com/mmcgrana/ring/blob/master/ring-core/src/ring/middleware/nested_params.clj) package.  The `wrap-nested-params` middleware works together with `wrap-params` - params puts the data in the request map's `:params` key, and nested params replaces it with the fully expanded input.

```clj
(use '[ring.middleware.params :only (wrap-params)])
(use '[ring.middleware.nested-params :only (wrap-nested-params)])

(def app (wrap-params (wrap-nested-params your-handler)))
```